# Twilio SMS message not sending when a user tweets Tweepy

Tags: python, heroku, twilio, tweepy

I am trying to send an SMS message from one Twilio phone number to another whenever a certain user tweets. Here is the code:

```
import tweepy
from twilio.rest import Client

consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY
consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN
access_token_secret = ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if status.user.id_str == "14173315":
            message = client.messages \
                .create(
                    body="Success!",
                    from_=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER_1,
                    to=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER_2
                )

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(follow=["14173315"])
```

This is being hosted on a Heroku worker dyno, so when the app is live, the Tweepy listener is always listening for tweets from the user with Twitter ID 14173315. However, whenever the user with Twitter ID 14173315 has tweeted, no SMS message is getting sent. I know this because I checked the Twilio SMS message logs and no messages are showing up between the two phone numbers. I do not know why this is happening. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing any errors from your application? Is your Twitter streaming API definitely receiving the tweets? (Separate question, Is there a reason you are sending messages between two Twilio numbers?)

Comment: There is a reason, and yes the twitter streaming api is receiving the tweets I believe, I will double check

Comment: Also, it was working before when instead of the "to" phone number being a Twilio phone number, the "to" phone number was my personal phone number. I had to make it another Twilio phone number because T-Mobile (including Sprint) has not launched their A2P 10DLC solution. So I'm not sure why no message is being sent when the "to" phone number is another Twilio phone number.

Comment: Are you seeing errors from the application? Or are you seeing any errors in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger)? You might not be able to send messages between your own Twilio numbers in order to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in the Twilio debugger, and I think this is because it's not registering that any message is being sent. I've been checking and every time a 
tweet has occurred, no message has shown up in the Twilio message logs. I need to be able to send a message to a phone number of some sort, and since I can't use my personal phone number, I bought another Twilio phone number to send messages to. So I can't send messages between my own Twilio phone numbers due to this infinite loop issue?

Comment: The application doesn't appear to be giving an error when the tweet occurs.

Comment: Can you update the app to print a message SID when the API request succeeds? So, after `message = client.messages.create(...)` run `print(message.sid)`. You can then follow the logs and see the messages that are supposedly getting created. It would probably help to `print(status.text)` just to ensure that the Tweet is arriving at your listener too. If you get a message SID then you should be able to see that in [the messaging logs in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs).

Comment: The only thing is that I am running this on a remote server, so how will I see the print messages?

Comment: You can check the heroku logs with `heroku logs --tail`.

Comment: Oh so that command shows print statements okay cool

Comment: It may also show up any errors that you hadn’t detected before. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting anything back from the logs. I put in both print statements and nothing is showing up. I'm going to try getting rid of the Twilio stuff and just seeing if the ```print(status.text)``` outputs anything.

Comment: Yup still nothing in the heroku logs...

Comment: Sounds like your code is not running! Do you have a `Procfile` to run the worker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234838/discussion-between-philnash-and-watersheep23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After a long conversation this turned out not to be an issue with either the Twitter streaming API or Twilio. Instead, the worker process was not running on Heroku.

When running a worker on Heroku you need to ensure that the worker process is started by Heroku. By default Heroku will start a "web" process, but you need to tell it to specifically start other processes.

To check whether there are any processes running, run:

```
heroku ps
```

and if you have a process defined in your `Procfile` called "worker" you can ensure that it is running in one dyno with the command:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

You can read more about [scaling dynos in the Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling).